# Are there any logics to formalize understanding?

Tags: lo.logic, temporal-logic, modal-logic

Are there any logics (modal-based or others) to formalize the following statement:

"agent A understands p". For example "agent A understands that Titanic sank
because it hit an iceberg"

Where "understands" could be considered as a modal operator like the epistemic modal operator "agent A knows p".

Thank you,

Comment: When I looked into logics for cryptographic protocols, I encountered two separate, versions of knowledge: "knowing a message" and "knowing that what a message claims is true". Is this the type of distinction you are trying to look into? If not, then it would help if you clarified a bit more on how your "understands" operator differs from a "knows" operator.

Comment: Perhaps justification logic? [link](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-justification)

Comment: In the context of distributed systems, Joseph Y. Halpern has studied ["reasoning about knowledge and uncertainty"](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/halpern/topics.html#raksurvey). However, for more specific answers, it would be better to clarify how "understands" differs from "knows", as indicated by @mdx . For example, are there some axioms on "knows" that "understands" does (or should, in your context) not satisfy?

Comment: @mdx: Maybe the question conveys some confusion. When I reefed to the epistemic modal operator  "know" I was referring to "knowing a message" as you've said. The difference is that I'm looking for a logic that can model the following attitude:
"agent A understands that Titanic sank because it hit an iceberg".

Comment: @LukaMikec: could you elaborate more please ? how do you see that justification is related to understanding ?

Comment: @hengxin: The idea is not that clear in my head, but anyway bear with me. "Agent A knows p" is interpreted as "in all possible worlds compatible with what A knows, it is the case that p", so I might know "the sun rises from the east" but this doesn't necessarily mean that "I understand why the sun rises from the east". Semantically, In all possible worlds compatible with what I know the sun rises from the east, but still I don't understand why. I hope I clarified the question. Thanks, mdx, Luka Mikec and hengxin for you interaction.

Comment: "Understanding" as "knowing why" has (perhaps) natural connection with justification. Perhaps not the one you're looking for; would you say you agree with some unobvious statement in a well known logic textbook, without knowing any concrete proof of that statement, yet having justification "I know all the axioms and rules they used, and I know that this textbook uses only proved formulas (so I'll regard knowing any concrete proof as a technical detail)"?

Comment: @Abdallah I don't know what the particulars are of the problem you are trying to solve, but I would roughly equate "understanding P" with "has a proof of P". Luka's recommendation of justification logic certainly seems to capture that and more. Are you looking for any convenient properties or features in a logic? For instance, do you have any requirements concerning decidability of fragments?

Comment: @mdx Maybe by clarifying the context we can come to a clearer account of the problem. The problem I'm trying to solve is the following: I want to formalize how humans use dialogues to arrive at the understanding of something (phenomenon, function , intention, etc.), let's call it explanation dialogue. The formalization of the dialogue needs a semantic, an important component of the semantic is a knowledge model (or a logic) where I can reason about the fact that "the explainer" is aware of the understanding state of the explainee, and if "the explainee" understands smthing or not, etc.

Comment: @LukaMikec and mdx, I'll try to reformulate your comments so that I can be sure I get the point, please correct me if I'm wrong. By using justification logic you mean "A understands p" iff "A has (or can generate) a proof (justification) of p" ? What do you think of the following formalization by means of the epistemic operator "know": "A understands p" iff "A knows a proof (justification) of p" ?

Comment: @Abdallah, that's what I meant. The question was supposed to check whether you're ok with such meaning of "understanding". Btw, afaik most justification logics are "made up" in a sense that they try to capture and directly formalize otherwise informal ideas (unlike some other modal logics like GL provability logic).